# Centering an image with varying width wider than parent container

Tags: html, css, image, shopify, centering

I'm trying to build a blog with a middle column of text, with images also centered on the page. I'd like the text 600px wide, but images can be up to 1024px wide and I'd like them to be centered on the page.

My weird constraint is that I'm using the Shopify platform and my code gets generated like this (i.e. the img is inside a p tag)

```
    <div class="container">
     <p>Hello 123, this is a blog post..</p>
     <p><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0296/9253/files/IMG_6009_1024x1024.JPG?14454" /></p>
     <p>This is also some text</p>
     </div>
```

So how do I write code that allows my images to hang outside the p tags when I don't know the images width? I could write a jQuery solution but ideally I'd write a CSS solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to centre elements:

Margin way:

With a set width or display: inline-block; you can use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

text-align way:

With a set width or display: inline-block; you can add this to the parent:

```
text-align: center;
```

Absolute way:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: width/2;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Also don't worry too much about ie7 and below as the the majority of people use higher versions of ie or a different browser though this should work up until ie6

Also if you just want to put it into HTML you can add this to the parent of the image:

```
align='center'
```

Comment: Thanks - I get centering the P tag OR the img tag - but how to center the p tags and p-with-img tags together? P should be 600px wide, img could be anything up to 1024px wide. Thanks

Comment: @tomcritchlow just add text-align: center to the container div

Comment: Sorry - I must be missing something. Check out my attempt here: http://htmlpad.org/fiercelycurious/

Comment: @tomcritchlow your problem is that the width of the p containing the image is set to 600px instead of 1024px change that and it works

Comment: But I want the p with only text to be 600px wide... How do I achieve that?

Comment: arr the images always going to be 1024px width @tomcritchlow

Comment: Just give the p element that will have images in a class and then set the width of that class to say 100% width text-align: center;